# Rate feedback to iOS applestore code does not work Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to give the ability for the user to send feedback/rate the app.

Android works and takes me to the playstore etc...

I always get back "false".
I have checked the appleid and it's correct.

iOS does not and do not understand what I am doing wrong?

Any suggestions?

```
public void LoadReviewPage(string appId)
{
    var url = $"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id{appId}?action=write-review";

    bool canOpenUrl=UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(url));
    if (!canOpenUrl)
    {
        //todo:display a message that you cannot open it
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //todo: log it
}
```

}

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using the wrong protocol, this should be done:

```
var url = $"https://itunes.apple.com/app/id{appId}?action=write-review";
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I get to a page but i get a message "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" I have checked the bundle identifier and its correct. Is there a public "appId" that i could try to test if works

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by simply using Xamarin.Forms built in method OpenUri.

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
 {
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourappid"));
 }
else
 {
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://itunes.apple.com/app/yourappid"));
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I followed this article  https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-reviews-ios-10-3s-skstorereviewcontroller/ but no lack . When you say "yourApp" you mean the appId?

Comment: Yep exactly your appId. We are using this in our app BootstrapService for a different purpose, which redirects user to playstore or itunes when there is an available update for our app, and its working perfectly.

Comment: still does not work. I wish I could with some appId other then mine to prove it works!

Comment: .It just does not open anything.Is there any public appId I could try.

Comment: It does NOTHING ? Did you try with a simple URI like https://www.google.com/  first ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190189/discussion-between-umar3x-and-developer9969).